# Pytorch Problem with Custom Dataset Class

Tags: pytorch

First, I made a custom dataset to load in images from my dataframe (containing the image filepath and corresponding int label):

```
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, dataframe, transform=None):
        self.frame = dataframe
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        filename = self.frame.iloc[idx, 0]
        image = torch.from_numpy(io.imread(filename).transpose((2, 0, 1))).float()
        label = self.frame.iloc[idx, 1]
        sample = {'image': image, 'label': label}
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)
        return sample
```

Then, I use pre-existing model architecture like so:

```
model = models.densenet161()
num_ftrs = model.classifier.in_features
model.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 10)  # where 10 is my number of classes

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

Finally, for training, I do the following:

```
model.train()  # switch to train mode
        
for epoch in range(5):
    for i, sample in enumerate(train_set):  # where train_set is an instance of my Dataset class
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        image, label = sample['image'].unsqueeze(0), torch.Tensor(sample['label']).long()
        output = model(image)

        loss = criterion(output, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

However, I am experiencing errors with `loss = criterion(output, label)`. It tells me that `ValueError: Expected input batch_size (1) to match target batch_size (2).`. Can someone teach me how to properly use a custom dataset, especially with loading in batches of data? Also, why am I experiencing that ValueError? Thank you!

Comment: how do you construct `train_set` from your `Dataset` class?

Comment: @Shawn Zhang dont return a dict at the end of your getitem just do it like this `image_tens = self.transforms(image) return image_tens, torch.tensor(labels)`

Answer (score 0):

please check the following lines:

`label = self.frame.iloc[idx, 1]` in dataset defination, you may print this to re-check, is this return two int

`image, label = sample['image'].unsqueeze(0), torch.Tensor(sample['label']).long()` in training code, you need to check the shape of the tensor